# $0 in a cgi perl script behaves differenty in /var/www/html and ~/public_html

Tags: apache, perl

so i have this script try.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

print "content-type: text/plain\n";
print "\n";

$ENV{PATH} = "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin";

my $date = `/bin/date`;

print "This is $0, now is $date \n";
```

in two locations: /vaw/www/html/website/cgi-bin/try.pl and /home/user/public_html/website/cgi-bin/try.pl
Depending on which one i open, i get different results:
/vaw/www/html/website/cgi-bin/try.pl gives me:

```
This is /var/www/html/website/cgi-bin/try.pl, now is Tue Mar 13 17:11:56 EET 2018
```

and /home/user/public_html/website/cgi-bin/try.pl gives me:

```
This is try.pl, now is Tue Mar 13 17:48:25 EET 2018
```

As you can see, the problem is that $0 only gives me the basename in public_html. I'll also add cgi-bin/.htaccess:

```
Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
AddHandler cgi-script .pl

<Files ~ "\.(conf|config)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Another test i did was on a different computer, and there $0 gave absolute path in both /var/www/html and public_html. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Why do you need `$0` and what is it giving you that `$ENV{"SCRIPT_NAME"}` doesn't?

Comment: I'll test $ENV{"SCRIPT_NAME"}, but what i need is to understand why it behaves differently when it shouldn't.

Comment: why shouldn't it? `$0` is the filename that is passed to Perl to run. If you call a script with the full path, you'll get that, but you can also call it with a relative path and that's all you'll get too.

Comment: I'm calling them though the browser, why is it being called from root on one pc and from cgi-bin in another? that's what i want to find out

Comment: No idea - you'll need to include the relevant parts of the Apache config for anyone to make an informed answer rather than guessing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know where a script resides, use the module [`FindBin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html). `FindBin` is a standard module and comes installed with Perl. For a list of standard modules, see [`perldoc perlmodlib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html).

Comment: http://images.use.perl.org/use.perl.org/_Aristotle/journal/33995.html https://metacpan.org/pod/Find::Lib

Comment: @daxim Then use `$FindBin::RealBin` instead of `$FindBin::Bin`.